# Android mobile app incorrectly converts 10 000 upvotes to 1k (should be 10k)

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When searching the top questions upvoted questions on a android device, it incorrectly shows question scores larger than 10k as 1k, example screenshots below:

On mobile (should display as 12K instead of 1,2k):
[image: Mobile screen shows question score as 1,2k]

On desktop:
[image: Desktop pc shows question score as 12K]

Link to question, it has 11898 question score at the moment of writing:

[Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

Comment: They should name this as the *1.2k problem*

Comment: Funny bug. I see how this would slip through during testing.

Comment: They just group things every μύριοι, ܪܒܘܬܐ, רבבה, 萬/万, 万/萬, 만/萬, หมื่น, or the like.  Seems like a reasonable standard to use.  The *k* is, however, a typo.  It should be myria and a prefix.

Comment: Duplicate of duplicate?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259662/proposed-fix-for-wrong-formating-of-the-vote-count-in-the-android-app

Comment: @Rolfツ By the number of upvotes, the others would be closed as duplicates of this now :P

Comment: @Siguza the point is that bug reports about the Android app should be posted to the SE meta not the SO meta. So this post is actually out of place.

Comment: Finally a good unit for Asian language speakers! (Yes we separate numbers in ten-thousands not thousands.)

Comment: I would prefer 1.2e4 anyway. :)

Comment: If it were 100 000 to 1k, then we could just do [1L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.79.

Formats won't exactly match the web because it has a more complex multilingual number formatter with four different modes for different part of the site.  The app just has one function that gets used everywhere.

```java
public static String miniNumber(double number) {
    if (number > 10000000) {
        return new DecimalFormat("0m").format(number / 1000000);
    } else if (number > 1000000) {
        return new DecimalFormat("0.#m").format(number / 1000000);
    } else if (number > 10000) {
        return new DecimalFormat("0k").format(number / 1000);
    } else if (number > 1000) {
        return new DecimalFormat("0.#k").format(number / 1000);
    } else {
        return new DecimalFormat("#,###").format(number);
    }
}
```